# Extract list elements using get() function in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list like this

```
x = list( 1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 100 )
```

The requirement is that I need to extract ith element from x - where i can be anything between 1 to 100 - and which i to extract, I will get this information from somewhere else as a character.

Let me explain.

Suppose I need to extract 'x[[8]]' . So how to do that utilizing this character ?

something like this

```
get( 'x[[8]]' )
```

I know that this does not work. But is there anything similar to this where I can give the element name in strings to get the value ?

Answer (score 5):

Once you `get` via character, you have the object.

So `get('x')[[8L]]` is fine.

I'm not sure what you mean by "give the element name in strings to get the value." If the list is named, just `x[['el_name']]` works.

Comment: This partially solves my problem. Actually I meant to say suppose I am given neither 'x' nor 'e1_name' but given

Comment: 'x[[e1_name]]' such as 'x[[8]]'

Comment: @boral please provide a reproducible example. it sounds like `get('x')[['el_name']]` is anyway fine.

Comment: 'x' and 'e1_name' are not given separately but together like this 'x[[e1_name]]' such as 'x[[8]]'

Comment: where did you get such a thing? eval(parse()) if you must

Comment: Thanks MichaelChirico ... this one works and is exactly the thing I was looking for. eval(parse(text = 'x[[8]]')) gave the desired result.

Comment: @joel.wilson feel free to undelete your answer